# Odoo V15 - How to set a line with an Onchange Function

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I have this calendar that is made with Javascript.

[image]

When you click in "Libre", a view opens, where you can create a reserve. I want the reservation line as default and look something like this. In this case I did it manually, and I want it to appear automatically. I know I need an on `@api.onchange` function.

[image]

The `roomid` field ("Room" in the image) has the ID of the room that I need to add in reservation.line. I get this from .js

I have something like this in my code and it's getting exactly the room I want, but I don't know how to make it appear automatically.

```
class HotelReservation(models.Model):
    _name = "hotel.reservation"
   
  room_id = fields.Many2one("hotel.room", string="Room", required=True)

  roomid= fields.Integer(related='room_id.id', string="Room")

  reservation_line = fields.One2many(
        "hotel.reservation.line",
        "line_id",
        string="Reservation Line",
        help="Hotel room reservation details.",
        readonly=True,
        states={"draft": [("readonly", False)]},
    )


   @api.onchange('roomid')
   def onchange_reservation_line(self):
        if self.roomid:
            room = self.env['hotel.room'].search([('id' ,'=', self.roomid)])
            # Some return here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in the [write](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.write) function documentation that the expected value of a [One2many](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.One2many) or [Many2many](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Many2many) relational field is a list of [Command](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command) that manipulates the relation the implement. There are a total of 7 commands: [create()](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command.create), [update()](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command.update), [delete()](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command.delete), [unlink()](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command.unlink), [link()](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command.link), [clear()](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command.clear), and [set()](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command.set).

`roomid` is related to `room_id` so you can use it in onchange function and avoid calling the search method to get the room record.

***Example:***

```
@api.onchange('room_id')
def onchange_reservation_line(self):
    if self.room_id:
        self.reservation_line = [
            Command.clear(),
            Command.create({
                'field_name': field_value,
                ...
            }),
        ]
```