# Update records on one2many fields in wizard for odoo16

Tags: odoo, onchange, one2many, odoo-16

Geting Issue **'TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'** for insert values in one2many field from onchange method in odoo16

My code is below:

```
class EmployeeAddWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'employee.add.wizard'

    line_ids = fields.One2many('employee.goal.add.line', 'wizard_id', string="Lines")
    
    @api.onchange('challenge_id', 'employee_id')
    def _onchange_action_goal_add(self):
        r = []
        value = {}
        self.line_ids = {}
        if self.challenge_id and self.employee_id:
            goal_records = self.env['gamification.challenge.line'].search([('challenge_id', '=', self.challenge_id.id)])
            for emp in self.employee_id:
                for line in goal_records:
                    data = {'wizard_id': self.id,  # Other table m2o
                            'goal_definition_id': line.definition_id.id,
                            'goal_rating': 0.0,
                            'goal_target': line.target_goal,
                            'employee_id': emp.id,
                            }
                    r.append(data)
            value.update(records=r)
            self.line_ids = value['records']
            
class GoalLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'employee.goal.add.line'


    wizard_id = fields.Integer()
    goal_definition_id = fields.Many2one('gamification.goal.definition', string='Goal Definition', required=True, ondelete="cascade")
    goal_rating = fields.Float('Rating', required=True)
    goal_target = fields.Float('Target Value ', required=True)
    employee_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string="Employee", required=True, ondelete="cascade")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed a list of dicts which is not valid, you need to use special [commands](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/fr/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command)

***Example:***

```
r.append(Command.create(data))
```

or:

```
r.append((0, 0, data))
```

You can use `Command.clear(),` to remove previous lines if needed ( `self.line_ids = {}` should raise an error: `ValueError: Wrong value`).

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74870521/odoo-v15-how-to-set-a-line-with-an-onchange-function/74873954#74873954)